# How can I get a VTT file to work with my mp4 on a streaming server?

Tags: video, mp4, jwplayer, webvtt, blackboard

I have several videos I am trying to add a VTT closed captioned file to. I am deploying the MP4 via JWPlayer 6.8 within Blackboard SP11. I'm having a hard time deciphering exactly what I need to do to get this to work. The MP4 is on a DIFFERENT server than where the VTT file.  I am told the streaming server does NOT support anything other than video so the VTT file has to be hosted elsewhere.

Does this mean I need to make an XML file based on the VTT? I can't find any good documentation on how to do this. Please help! Here is the code:

```
    <script src="http://jwpsrv.com/library/lQk4GLbAEeOZLiIACmOLpg.js"></script>
<div id='mediaplayer'></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  jwplayer('mediaplayer').setup({
    playlist: [{
      file: 'rtmp://videoserver.example1.com/vod/mp4:HSH/Smith/ARTS4439/M1S1_CamControls1.mp4',
      height: '720',
      width: '480',
      tracks: [{
file: "http://example2.com/M1S1_CamControls1.vtt",
label: "English",
kind: "captions",
default: "true"
}]
}]
});
</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Because your stream and your captions are on different domains, you must provide a crossdomain XML file. It's not the *captions* that go into the XML file - the XML file simply identifies what *domains* are allowed to load content.

See http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1403679-crossdomain-file-loading

Comment: For Flash, indeed, but for HTML5, CORS has to be enabled.